# How do I display a SharePoint Calendar with more than 5,000 items in Outlook?

Tags: outlook

We have SharePoint Online as part of Office365.  We use a couple of SharePoint calendars for booking recording studio time, which are accessed via Outlook.  Unfortunately each calendar hare more than 5,000 items in it.

There's lots of information about how to handle lists larger than 5,000 items within the SharePoint environment but I don't see any solutions when the list is being consumed by Outlook.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?

Comment: Nope. I did not.